502 Bad Gateway Nginx Error Flask Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk
I'm trying to host a backend Flask server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I'm encountering a 502 Bad Gateway error whenever I try to access the webpage. The health status in the AWS portal is listed as "Severe" and I've never been able to view the page I expect so there was never a point where it was working and then stopped. This is all the code in my application.py file. I've successfully hosted my frontend server running Vue.js and Node.js and I'm trying to get the backend server up as well so I can make sure I can hit the endpoints correctly. Everything works correctly when I run it locally.
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return jsonify("homepage")

@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    return jsonify('FLASK server running!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()   

I've tried to investigate the security groups for the EC2 instances and they all allow inbound traffic from port 80 and allow outbound traffic everywhere. These are the events that I can see in my Elastic Beanstalk portal. Below I have a snippet of the elastic beanstalk logs I can view locally (eb logs).
172.31.35.119 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:18:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.15.189 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:18:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.35.119 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.15.189 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.35.119 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.35.119 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "70.115.140.178"
172.31.35.119 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:24 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "http://abc-backend.eba-548pqri3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "70.115.140.178"
172.31.15.189 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.35.119 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.15.189 - - [02/Jun/2024:22:19:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"

I'm not sure what steps I can take from here as I can't find much debug information to go off of. Any help is appreciated.
